# How do I explode string on blank line?

Tags: php

I am trying to find solution to this.
How do I explode the data below
Sample Data :
===========

```
"2013:
Fondermann LP
Hold your Ground LP

2012:
Zwo:80 MiniLP
Sassy Society Demo
Pogo Samplerbeitrag
Sir Hake Samplerbeiträge

2011:
My Favourite Mixtape LP
Surfits LP"
```

The expected output :

```
Array{
   [0]=>2013:Fondermann LP Hold your Ground LP
   [1]=>2012: Zwo:80 MiniLP Sassy Society Demo Pogo Samplerbeitra
   [2]=>2011:My Favourite Mixtape LP Surfits LP}
```

how do I achive this ?

**PS:** I am new to PHP technology.

Thanks,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this, It worked for me in one of my solution

```
$yourString = "2013:
Fondermann LP
Hold your Ground LP

2012:
Zwo:80 MiniLP
Sassy Society Demo
Pogo Samplerbeitrag
Sir Hake Samplerbeiträge

2011:
My Favourite Mixtape LP
Surfits LP";

$output  = preg_split("#\n\s*\n#Uis", $yourString);
print_r($output);
```

I used preg_split not explode.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `explode` function and then `array_map` to format array. try below solution:

```
$str = "2013:
Fondermann LP
Hold your Ground LP

2012:
Zwo:80 MiniLP
Sassy Society Demo
Pogo Samplerbeitrag
Sir Hake Samplerbeitrage

2011:
My Favourite Mixtape LP
Surfits LP";

$array = explode("\n\n", $str);

//print_r($array);

$new_array = array_map(function($v){
return str_replace("\n", " ", $v);
}, $array);

print_r($new_array);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2013: Fondermann LP Hold your Ground LP
    [1] => 2012: Zwo:80 MiniLP Sassy Society Demo Pogo Samplerbeitrag Sir Hake Samplerbeitrage
    [2] => 2011: My Favourite Mixtape LP Surfits LP
)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this below code,

```
$str= "2013:
Fondermann LP
Hold your Ground LP

2012:
Zwo:80 MiniLP
Sassy Society Demo
Pogo Samplerbeitrag
Sir Hake Samplerbeiträge

2011:
My Favourite Mixtape LP
Surfits LP";
print_r(explode("\n\n",$str));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to split on empty lines using a regex:

```
$r = preg_split('/^\s*$/' , $input);
```